# Browser memory leak while sending socket requests

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I try to send websocket requests (socket.io) on server. The requests are sent from browser console. But I get memory leak while using the script in browser. Would you help to avoid memory leak, but to save script 
productivity? Code:

```
var socket = new io;
var counter = 251;

function myNewFunction(data){   
try{
    var IDs = {"items": []};
    var arrayLength = data.items.length;
    var lables = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i ++){
        if(data.items[i]["amount"] < 20){
            IDs["items"].push(data.items[i]["_id"]);
            lables.push(data.items[i]["amount"]);

}}}catch(err){}

if (IDs["items"].length > 0){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "url", false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(IDs));
    if (xhr.status == 200){
        for(var i = 0; i < lables.length; i ++){
            counter -= lables[i];}
        console.log("Left", counter);
    }}
}

setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit("/call/items", {page: 1, sort: 1, search: "", tags: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]}, function(e, data){myNewFunction(data)})
}, 100)
```

Comment: That setInterval seems evil. You should probably wait for a response before emitting more.

Comment: Speed  of requests is the most important. I'm not JS developer so I don't understand many things. would you please help how to do this?

Comment: You are emitting each 100 milliseconds, that is quite fast. I believe your server is not responding fast enough, and what is happening is that more and more requests are stacking up each time.
So, if you don't use the setInterval, but instead you do a new request just right after you get a response, the server will response as fast as possible but not get collapsed as it seems is happening

Comment: Roman Cortes. Would you please give an example of code where I send request right after server response instead of "SetInterval" function

Comment: Ok, give me a minute...

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
var socket = new io;
var counter = 251;

function myNewFunction(data) {
    try {
        var IDs = {"items": []};
        var arrayLength = data.items.length;
        var lables = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i ++) {
            if(data.items[i]["amount"] < 20) {
                IDs["items"].push(data.items[i]["_id"]);
                lables.push(data.items[i]["amount"]);
            }
        }
        if (IDs["items"].length > 0) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "url", false);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(IDs));
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.status == 200){
                    for(var i = 0; i < lables.length; i ++){
                        counter -= lables[i];}
                    setTimeout(callItems, 100);
                }
            }
        } else {
            setTimeout(callItems, 100);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        setTimeout(callItems, 100);
    }
}

function callItems() {
    socket.emit(
        "/call/items",
        {page: 1, sort: 1, search: "", tags: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]},
        function (e, data) {
            myNewFunction(data)
        }
    );
}

callItems();
```

Comment: In general, I'm looking for some items on a site and if found  - purchase them. XHR request is purchasing request

Comment: Ok so, the xhr send is asynchronous. So, your code that checks for the xhr status is not good because at that point it won't have received an answer yet. I'm going to update the code with the xhr then...

Comment: I was using synchronous requests but again because of lack JS coding knowledges. Would you think async requests will be better?

Comment: Thank you very much for help. You realy did a fantastic  job. I Marked you answer, but it don't show in my request because of low reputation. Anyway is should be recorded for you in your account. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful!